# How to create app info page

Tags: android, eclipse-adt

I need to create a page for an android app that displays info about the app. App version, db version, php version, etc.

Is there a simple way of doing this or should I just write it all on a page with and XML ?

I was to use the default android libraries. Where do I find that?

Answer (score 0):

You can follow Android Style by using [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html)